# Getting text elements of svg by dblclick event

Tags: javascript, svg, jointjs

This is an example for an SVG element. With a doubleclick I want to get the text content to display this in a textarea.
But in my attempt it is depending on the excact place where the user is clicking: I get just one line as the user is clicking on a line-element and I get an empty value if the user is clicking not exactly on a line (but still inside of the g-element).

**SVG**

```
<g id="j_7" model-id="15449af1-b873-4d0f-92da-ca064c322b77">

    <rect id="v-41"></rect>

    <text id="v-46" y="0.8em" display="null" xml:space="preserve">
        <tspan id="v-139" class="line">Line 1</tspan>
        <tspan id="v-140" class="line">Line 2</tspan>
        <tspan id="v-141" class="line">Line 3</tspan>
    </text>
</g>
```

**JS**

dblclick event using JointJS (as it is part of an diagram-editor)

```
'cell:pointerdblclick': function(cellView, event, x, y){
    var content = event.target.innerHTML;

        $('#target').prepend('<textarea id="overlay">' + content + '</textarea>');
        $('#overlay').focus().select();                
},
```

So what I need is

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

as `content` to display this in the textarea if the user is doubleclicking somewhere in the g-element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the text stored in a property (which should be the case) or an attribute, it's better to do something like:

```
'cell:pointerdblclick': function(cellView, event, x, y) {
    var content = cellView.model.get('mytext'); // in case the text is in a property
    var content = cellView.model.attr('text/text') // in case the text is in an attribute

    $('#target').prepend('<textarea id="overlay">' + content + '</textarea>');
    $('#overlay').focus().select();
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery to extract the text

```
'cell:pointerdblclick': function(cellView, event, x, y) {
    var content = cellView.$el.find('tspan').map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get().join("\n");

    $('#target').prepend('<textarea id="overlay">' + content + '</textarea>');
    $('#overlay').focus().select();
},
```